# Confusion about Data Access Objects and Observer pattern

Tags: design-patterns, dao, observer-pattern

I'm trying to use the Data Access Object and Observer pattern in my Android app. The app shows a list of meals that the user has eaten on a given day and their calories. The user can delete the item from the list.

The code works like this:

- The Activity class uses a method in the Meal Data Access Object to return a list of meals and calories `List<Meal> = MealDAO.getAllMeals();`
- The list is stored in the Meal Model: `mealModel.setMealsList(mealList)`
- The Meal Model is `Observable` and is passed to the `ListView` adapter which is an `Observer`
- When the user deletes a meal from the listView, the Activity uses a DAO method to remove the meal from the database. `MealDAO.remove(3);`
- The Activity then resets the list in the model, which calls notifyObservers and the adapter is updated.

  //after deletion

  newMealList = MealDAO.getAllMeals();

  mealModel.setMealList(newMealList);

I'm not sure this is a good way to do this because I have to reset the list in the mealModel. Is there a better way to do this or is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should not talk to DAO directly.

I'd replace `MealDAO.remove(3);` with something like `MealDAO.removeById(idOfMeal);`

You would need to remove meal from `ListView` and then compare that list with the list that was present there before removal, to find the removed item.

Pass this item (or even better - its ID) to DAO, and remove it from DB

You dont need to *reset the list in the mealModel* if you are sure that this is the only place where you modify the state of Meals in DB. So its safer to reset it.